# Unicode property "Space" in Perl 5 and Perl 6

Tags: perl, unicode, whitespace, raku

Is the unicode-property `\p{Space}` a Perl5 extension?

In Perl5 `Space` matches all white-spaces

```
my $s = "one\ttwo\nthree";
$s =~ s/\p{Space}/*/g;
say $s;

# one*two*three
```

while in Per6 it maybe matches only a simple space

```
my $s = "one\ttwo\nthree";
$s.=subst( /<:Space>/, '*', :g );
say $s;

# one     two
# three
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really an extension, but it's a shorthand name for another Unicode property, `\p{White_Space}`. This is documented in detail in the manpage `perluniprops`.

I have no idea what the Perl6 people are doing here.

Answer (score 7):

Tabulators are of category *Control*, not *Space*. The property you're interested in is actually called *White_Space*, and that's what you need to use in Perl 6:

```
say so "\t" ~~ /<:White_Space>/
```

Several alternative spellings appear to be available as well, including *WhiteSpace*, *WSpace* and its lower-case variants, but **not** *WS*.

There is also a built-in rule `<ws>`, which matches zero or more whitespace characters instead of a single one, and of course `\s`, which already uses Unicode semantics.

Comment: I have it already replaced with `<:White_Space>` but I was curious why `Space` behaves differently in Perl5/Perl6.

Comment: @sid_com: it's just that Perl5 chose to alias `\p{Space}` to `\p{White_Space=Y}` instead of `\p{General_Category=Space}`

Comment: or rather, `\p{General_Category=Zs}`

Comment: Oh, dear.  That's the sort of subtle correction that will yield years of debugging fun.